# Групп или группы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: На празднике перед ветеранами выступили дети старшей и младшей группы или групп. Дети старшей и младшей группы (или групп) посетили цирк. Не говорим же мы дети младшего и старшего возрастов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы выбрал множественное число: *"…старшей и младшей **групп**".*

А вот слово ***дети,*** если бы это было возможно, заменил бы на, к примеру, ***воспитанники, ученики, учащиеся...***

Answer (score 1):

А я бы выбрал единственное число.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm (§194. Два определения при одном существительном)

1. Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится в форме единственного числа:

......

```
4) если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в правой и левой руке (половине, стороне и т.п.); оперное и балетное искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот ... ...
```

Comment: Здесь связанность этих объектов сомнительна. Ко всему прочему рекомендация вашего источника судя по всем не несет императивного характера, а лишь рекомендательная.

Answer (score 1):

```
Если при имени существительном имеются два или несколько определении, перечисляющих разновидности  предметов,  то  это существительное может стоять как в единственном, так и во множественном числе, а именно:
```

> а) единственное число подчеркивает связь определяемых предметов, их терминологическую близость: ***в правой и левой половине дома, уголовное и гражданское право; учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного возраста; программы для восьмилетней и средней школы (как системы образования);***
>  единственное число употребляется, если определения выражены порядковыми числительными или местоимениями-прилагательными: дипломы первой и второй степени, та и другая сторона:

б) множественное число подчеркивает наличие нескольких предметов:

Западный и Северный округа: в Октябрьском и Орджоникидзевском управлениях внутренних дел.

***В вашем случае  возможно и ед.ч и мн.ч. (если важно подчеркнуть количество)** .

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно говорить, "группы'".

Comment: Не вижу причин для такого употребления. Возможно, я не совсем понял, это родительный единственного или именительный множественного?!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?